# How to execute a script based on the output of a command

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I am trying to set up a cron job that will keep alive a process that is running on a particular port in a centos server.

Based on the previous discussions I have come up with the following script which will be called by a cron job:

```
#!/bin/bash
opt="$(lsof -i tcp:9090| awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}')"
echo $opt
if [ -z "$opt" ]
then
    # nohup npm start & 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
    echo "App Restarted" | mail -s "App is restarted"  "myemail"
fi
```

This gets triggered irrespective of the value in the variable output, not sure what is wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

```
#assign output of a command to a variable
output="$(command)"

#test variable to see if empty
if [ -z "$output" ]
then
   #do something
   a_command
fi
```

Comment: I have created the following script: #!/bin/bash
output="$(lsof -i tcp:9090| awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}')"

#test variable to see if empty
if [[ "!" -z "$output" ]]
then
   #do something
   echo "reaching here"
fi    Now I am getting error as line 5: conditional binary operator expected
line 5: syntax error near `-z'
line 5: `if [[ "!" -z "$output" ]] '

Comment: Only unquoted `!` inside `[[ ]]` negates. (Quoted `!` is good inside `[ ]`). Why not `-n` instead of `! -z`?

Comment: I have made minor update to the if and was able to solve my issue: if [ -z "$output" ]

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Did I make an error leaving the `"!"` in?

Comment: Consult with OP if the negation shall be in place, but in any case, without double quotes. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, done, sorry for late edits, I haven't seen it sooner. Cheers!

Comment: My point was `[[ "!" -z "$foo" ]]` yields an error while `[[ ! -z "$foo" ]]` or `[ ! -z "$foo" ]` or `[ "!" -z "$foo" ]` works.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Oh yes. I was imagining that "[[' was like test: a command that took arguments, however it seems not to be. `bash` is parsing it defferently.